# How to reorder children by priority in Firebase/angularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to reorder (swap) children by their numerical priority.
Here's my attempt:

```
var swapChildrenByPriority = function(url, child1Priority, child2Priority){
  var ref = new Firebase(url);
  var child1, child2;
  ref.on('value', function(snap){
    snap.forEach(function(child){
      if(child.getPriority() === child1Priority){
        child1 = child;
      };
      if(child.getPriority() === child2Priority){
        child2 = child;
      };
    });
  });
  ref.child(child1.name()).setPriority(child2.getPriority());
  ref.child(child2.name()).setPriority(child1.getPriority());
};
```

As you can imagine, this doesn't work. 
Chrome's console throws errors at me when this function is called:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'name' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'name' of undefined
```

It looks as if the children have no priority set, when they do. If I import my data in Forge, all children have the property ".priority" : 5.0.
And when I call the function yet again, just to make sure, I get this one:

```
TypeError: Object https://test.firebaseio.com/testPriority has no method 'child'
```

What is the right way to do this in firebase?
Also, how to do the same in AngularFire, so that the data in the scope of a directive that is using angularFire service gets reordered accordingly, and the view gets refreshed?

I very much appreciate your time,
regards
Jared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the functions inside the callback from the DB:

```
fb.on('value', function(snap){
    snap.forEach(function(child){
        if(child.getPriority() === child1Priority) {
            child1 = child;
        }
        if(child.getPriority() === child2Priority){
            child2 = child;
        };
    });
    ref.child(child1.name()).setPriority(child2.getPriority());
    ref.child(child2.name()).setPriority(child1.getPriority());
});
```

Comment: Please see my question again. It is inside a callback from the db.

Comment: This answer looks correct to me. In your code, child1 and child2 would not have been initialized yet, because the callback from on() may not have been called yet.